# How to iterate records which is stored in databases?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I need iterate the records and display the data. For example, This is the data stored in database :

[image: This is the data stored in database]

```
FOR EACH tt_shift NO-LOCK BY tt_shift.shft_start_hour BY tt_shift.shft_stop_hour:   
i = i + 1. END.
```

As you know well i am iterating records and storing total count in i variable.If you see the picture which is attached in body, start and stop hour is stored in database.Now what i want is when its complete the first iteration it should show the first row of start and stop hour likewise need to show rest of all individually.Any helps are appreciated.

Note-I need to use the same variables to show every start and end hour after one iteration completes.

Comment: Provide some sample data showing what your output should look like. Based on what you "want" I have no clue.

Comment: in 1 Iteration:  assign i = 06:00, in 2 iteration assign i = 07:00, in 3rd Iteration assign i = 08:00 like wise when complete one iteration i need to assign the values to same variables.got my point?

Comment: So this actually has nothing to do with iterating anything and is really all about assigning the shift_start_hour to the variable "i"?

Comment: yes sir..actually we want to show the data for every iteration to the clients not whole data when iteration is completed.can you help this case?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "i" is an integer and that tt_shift.shft_start_hour is a character string (as shown) and that you want "i" in seconds:

```
FOR EACH tt_shift NO-LOCK BY tt_shift.shft_start_hour BY tt_shift.shft_stop_hour:

  i = integer( entry( 1, tt_shift.shft_start_hour, ":" )) * 3600 + integer( entry( 2, tt_shift.shft_start_hour, ":" )).

  display i.

END.
```

The "tt_" prefix to the table name implies that you are working with a temp table.  Temp-tables don't have locks so NO-LOCK is not needed.

Comment: in 1 Iteration:  assign i = 06:00, in 2 iteration assign i = 07:00, in 3rd Iteration assign i = 08:00 like wise when complete one iteration i need to assign the values to same variables.got my point sir?

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR EACH tt_shift
      BY tt_shift.shft_start_hour 
      BY tt_shift.shft_stop_hour:

    accum tt_shift.shft_start_hour (count).

    disp accum count tt_shift.shft_start_hour label "Sequence"
         tt_shift.shft_start_hour             label "Start"
         tt_shift.shft_stop_hour              label "Stop".
END.
```

Note: You don't need use "no-lock" for temp-tables;
      If use accum, don't need "count" var.